# Struggling to implement QR Code/Barcode scanner in mobile website application

Tags: html, responsive-design, camera, barcode, qr-code

I am building a mobile web application (so a website that is intended solely for mobile view), and I am trying to implement a QR code/barcode scanner by using their device's camera.

**Problem:** My main struggle is that there does not seem to be a lot of support/help in this area. I have been using https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode, which seems to work if I upload a direct image of a QR code, but when I add whitespace to the code, or take a picture of it, it does not work. However, everything seems to work fine on the website that it is implemented on (http://www.webqr.com/index.html). 
I essentially used the "test' file in his git source then modified it a tiny bit so that it read the image I display on the website.

**Question:** Can someone help me figure out if I need to include more of his libraries, or how I can go about getting my QR reader to decipher less visible QR Codes, or those taken within a camera? The webqr.com website works just fine, but his test file does not seem to have the same power implemented within it.

**Example:** You can test my current setup at http://aawebapps.com/echo/. Uploading a perfect QR image works fine, like (*Example of working QR Code* https://i.stack.imgur.com/L353H.jpg), but if there is any whitespace added, or if you give it an image taken with a camera (using your phone on the website), then it does not work. (*Example of whitespace not making it work* https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNdNR.jpg).

- Note: when you add another image, it won't erase the last number code shown if the new image has an error. (I will update that tonight when I am home)

**Goal:** The goal is for a user to bring up the website on their mobile device (most likely phone), then scan a QR Code or Barcode and then display its embedded number.

Answer (score 0):

For QRcode scanning, I've just implemented this successfully:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ilrm9

But for barcode, I'm still struggling to find a stable implementation in javascript. What I'm thinking is getting the image capture from the client and processing it in the server side for reading and sending back to web client in text format.

Comment: I suggest you try what you have in mind and then share here exactly what didn't work out. This is too vague.